# Visualization of three-dimensional report

Tags: marketing, infographics, visualization

I have a visualization problem.

Creating a comparison report of PR event efficiency. Say, show or exhibition.

There are two dimensions of comparison:

- compare vs the same event performance in the past years
- compare vs another type of analogical/competitive events

There is also a number of comparison aspects:

- Audience
- Media Coverage
- Social Buzz
- ROI
- .... etc

Each aspect is a set of some final KPI-s (just numbers, which can be compared vs another "dimensions"), plus maybe some descriptive text and pictures (which couldn't be a metric but should be attached to the report).

So finaly it looks like a three-dimensional coube:

1. Years
2. Another Events
3. Aspects

If I put it in plain Word or PPT it will look like a document with dozen of slides/papers and linear structure.

Any ideas how to compile an elegant user-friendly report?